# Register double clicks on a row in a list view

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have the following list view in a user control. I would like to register a double click on the entire row. When a double click is registered, I would like to call an `ICommand` in my view model.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

I know there are other posts about this and I have tried the solutions found in them (using both MVVM Light and AttachedCommandBehavior) but either the double click is simply not registered or it tries to call the ICommand on my `TVSeries` object which is my model and which holds the data presented in the rows.

This is my list view:

```
<ListView Height="456"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="12,12,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="488"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Library}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTVSeries}">

    <ListView.View>

        <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
                            Width="Auto">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Year"
                            Width="Auto">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Year}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Genre"
                            Width="Auto">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Genre}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>

    </ListView.View>

</ListView>
```

**UPDATE**

When using [AttachedCommandBehavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) I will get the following error:

> **NullReferenceException was unhandled**
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error occurs on the following lines (which are a part of AttachedCommandBehavior):

```xml
/// <summary>
/// Executes the strategy
/// </summary>
public void Execute()
{
   strategy.Execute(CommandParameter);
}
```

I use ACB like below. First I declare my style for the ListViewItem.

<-- language: xml -->

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LibraryListViewItemStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="acb:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="MouseDoubleClick" />
        <Setter Property="acb:CommandBehavior.Action" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.TVSeriesDoubleClickedCommand}" />
        <Setter Property="acb:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding }" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then I set the `ItemContainerStyle` on my list view to the style.

```
<ListView Height="456"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="12,12,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="488"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Library}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTVSeries}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LibraryListViewItemStyle}">

...

</ListView>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? This is really the closest I have been.

** UPDATE: Solution**

The above error occurred, because I have configured AttachedCommandBehavior to expect an action, but I had implemented a command. Changing from the following

`<Setter Property="acb:CommandBehavior.Action" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.TVSeriesDoubleClickedCommand}" />`

To the following

`<Setter Property="acb:CommandBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.TVSeriesDoubleClickedAction}" />`

That solved the error.

However, I found that I prefer using an action so I kept `acb:CommandBehavior.Action` and changed my implementation:

```
public Action<object> TVSeriesDoubleClickedAction
{
    get
    {
        return new Action<object>(tvSeries => Console.WriteLine("*** Double clicked fired: {0}", ((TVSeries)tvSeries).Name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or it tries to call the ICommand on my TVSeries object which is my model and which holds the data presented in the rows.

This would happen because you have your binding to your ICommand set incorrectly.  I would suggest going back to one of the solutions you've tried where it was calling the ICommand on the TVSeries object and try changing your binding to something similar to this:

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.YourCommandName}"
```

Comment: When using `AttachedCommandBehaviour` the target was my model so I tried your advice and while I got closer, it still doesn't work. I will get a `NullReferenceException` now. You can see my original question for more information.

Comment: When in break mode in the area of the NullReferenceException error, can you tell which object is null?  My guess would be the strategy object?  What is that and where should it be getting set?

Comment: The `strategy` is null and the `CommandParameter` is an instance of my model (an instance of the `TVSeries` class). The `strategy` is supposed to be an instance of `IExecutionStrategy`. There are two possible places for this to be set, either in the setter for `Command` or in the setter for `Action` but none of these are ever called. Note, this is not my code. This is part of the AttachedCommandBehaviour library.

Comment: I found the solution. Please see my original post, if you are interested. Thank you very much for the help. I couldn't have done this without you :-)